# Facebook OAuth login bug

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am trying to sign in Facebook with OAuth. I use following url:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=233884670034708&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fdemoappfbm&scope=publish_stream&response_type=token

However, I always receive following error:

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.
```

What is possible reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your Canvas APP Url as redirect-uri, so the actual place your app is located, not on facebook.

Comment: Then you can put my answer as the correct one. Glad to help :)